# pdo mysql data retreival

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

Please help with my database design or sql optimization:
I have two tables stock and stock_tally. The stock table contain the list of items while the stock_tally contains all transactions on the items.

[image]

```
My Queries?
```

Add new product

1. add product to stock table
2. add same to stock_tally

Issue product

1. remove stock from stock table
2. enter code here retrieve stock_level from stock table
3. add the stock_level and the quantity to issue into stock_tally

Issue code

```
 try{
            $this->db->beginTransaction();

            $q1 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE stock SET stock_level =? where id=?");

            $res1 = $q1->execute(array($qty, $id ));


    $q2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE id= ?");
        $q2->bindValue(1, $id);
        $q2->execute();
        $res2 = $q2->fetch();


    $q3 = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO stock_TALLY (id_fk, stocl_level, issues, update) VALUES (?,?,?,?)" );
        $res3 = $q1->execute(array($id,$res2,0, $qty));

    if($res2 && $res3){
      $this->db->commit();
              return true;

    }


    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->db->rollBack();   //echo  $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is not the site for this kind of question. This looks like a homework assignment. StackOverflow is the site to ask questions about specific issues you are having with a piece of code, not to write code for you. What have you tried? What errors are you getting? How do your results differ from what you are expecting to achieve?

Comment: Well, my code is working fine. i only feel there should be a better logic of getting it done. instead of this my round tripling. I am a beginner though.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you would do when designing a database is to write down clearly what it should be able to do, now, and possibly in the near future. You haven't done that, or at least you haven't told us. How do you expect us to tell you whether your database design and sql are optimal?

Comment: thanks, did not have any error my code works but i am only want to improve on my programming logic.

Comment: Yes, I think there's lots to improve, but I cannot tell what if I don't know the reasons for the current design. For a starter course see: http://r937.com/relational.html